# I cant turn the audio playback off in ExoPlayer! NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am facing with an issue: I cant turn the playback of audio off

it is error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference
    at com.dglasmann.radioapp.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:37)
```

Here is the code of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    Button btn, btn2;
    boolean isplaying;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isplaying = false;
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isplaying) {
                initplayer();
                isplaying = true;
            }
            });
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (isplaying) {
                simpleExoPlayer.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initplayer() {
        SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,"app"));
        MediaSource audiosource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(datasourcefactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://stream.audioxi.com/SW"));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(audiosource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        simpleExoPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        simpleExoPlayer.release();
        super.onPause();
    }
    public void pause() {
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

the error appears when i call btn2.setOnClickListener. I understand that i refer to another simpleExoPlayer which is not it "initplayer" function so that's why i have this error. But I have no Idea how to refer to simpleExoPlayer which function "initplayer" contain.
If i dont press btn2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because in initplayer() u are creating a new instance of ExoPlayer. So to solve it just change your initplayer to:

```
public void initplayer() {
    simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    DataSource.Factory datasourcefactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,"app"));
    MediaSource audiosource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(datasourcefactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://stream.audioxi.com/SW"));
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(audiosource);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```